# is there a posibility to create a message dialog that will stay on top of all the other windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to create a GUI for my class management software. I need a message that will pop up to the teacher and will ask him if he wants to stop operation. due to that the message must appear on top of all the other windows

I've tried to create a wx.message_dialog using the flag: style = wx.STAY_ON_TOP
but its not working

```
def stopscreen(self): 
    stopBox = wx.MessageDialog(None, "do you want to stop","stop controling", style=wx.STAY_ON_TOP | wx.YES_NO | wx.CENTRE)
    stopBoxAns = stopBox.ShowModal()
    if stopBoxAns == 5103:
        stopBox.Destroy()
        return 1### ok
    if stopBoxAns == 5104:
        stopBox.Destroy()
        return 2### cancel
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work, as you have coded it, unless you are on a Mac.

> wx.STAY_ON_TOP: Makes the message box stay on top of all other windows and not only just its parent (currently implemented only under MSW and GTK)

If you are still having trouble, try setting the window style to STAY_ON_TOP as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        button = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Show MessageDialog", (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, event):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Hello from wxPython!',
                               'A Message Box',
                               wx.YES | wx.NO | wx.ICON_INFORMATION | wx.STAY_ON_TOP
                               )
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    MyFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: you right it should work but it dosent. but you right! when i change the frame its really work. i need that the frame will stay under the other windows while i implement some operations with the program. i thought to change the window style twice (once to STAY_ON_TOP and second to defult) is there a simle way to do it